# Reading a file line by line and it is only storing the last line in the file

Tags: c, fgets

I have to read from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
New York,4:20,3:03
Kansas City,12:03,3:00
North Bay,16:00,0:20
Kapuskasing,10:00,4:02
Thunder Bay,0:32,0:31
```

I am trying to separate each element into its own array is the end goal so I can use it for something else.

My while loop reads the file correctly, but is only storing the last line of the file in an array and I cant figure out the reason for this. Also file being read could be any number of lines. I am sure its reading each line, as it prints each line it reads perfectly. So I believe the issue lies in storing what it is reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

// a function to remove the trailing carriage return
void clearTrailingCarraigeReturn(char *buffer);

/* == FUNCTION PROTOTYPES == */

/* == CONSTANTS == */
#define RECORD_SIZE     256
#define NUM_RECORDS     5
#define CHUNK_SIZE  1024    
#define STRING_SIZE 80

// MAIN
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE    *fp;
    char    flightInfo[RECORD_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char    cityName[20] = {};
    char    flightHour[20] = {};
    char    flightMin[20] = {};
    char    layoverHour[20] = {};
    char    layoverMin[20] = {};
    int     i = 0;

    struct flightInfo {
        char flightName[20];
        double flightTime;
        double layoverTime;
    };

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    // first - we'll check the command-line arguments to ensure that the user specified 
    // a single argument - which we will assume is the name of a file
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Sorry - you need to specify the name of a file on the command line.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open the TEXT file for reading\n");
        return -4;
    }

    // get each of the lines from the file
    while (fgets(flightInfo, sizeof flightInfo, fp) > 0) {
        clearTrailingCarraigeReturn(flightInfo);
        // display the line we got from the file
        printf("  >>> read record [%s]\n", flightInfo);
    }

    // we exited the reading loop - was it because we read the EOF?
    if (feof(fp)) {
        printf(" [DONE reading the file ... we've reached the EOF]\n");
    } else {
        // we exited the loop because of an error
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            // there's an error
            printf("Error reading a record from the file\n");
            if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
                // we can't even close the file
                printf("Can't close the TEXT file we opened for reading\n");
            }
            return -5;
        }
    }
}

// This function locates any carriage return that exists in a record
// and removes it ...
void clearTrailingCarraigeReturn(char *buffer) {
    char *whereCR = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    if (whereCR != NULL) {
        *whereCR = '\0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should test if the command line argument is present **before** trying to open the file.
- the test for your reading loop is incorrect: `fgets()` return a pointer to the destination array or `NULL`, so you should not use `> 0` but this instead:

  ```
  while (fgets(flightInfo, sizeof flightInfo, fp) != 0)
  ```
- the character `'\n'` is called *newline*, not carriage return. On legacy platforms, `\n` is converted to 2 bytes in text files `0D` `0A` ie: *carriage return* and *line feed*.
- the loop reads the file contents, but does not parse the line contents and store it into the variables you defined for that. You should parse the line, convert the values and store the info into the next entry in a `flighInfo` structure array:

  ```
      if (sscanf(flightInfo, "%19[^,],%2[0-9]:%2[0-9],%2[0-9]:%2[0-9]",
                 cityName, flightHour, flightMin, layoverHour, layoverMin) == 5) {
          /* convert the times into `double` values and store the info */
      } else {
          /* report the error, exit */
      }
  ```
- you use the same name for the `struct flightInfo` tag and the `char` array. This is confusing and error prone. You should rename the `char` array `line` or `buf`.
- you should close the file in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing the results of scan.  These lines:

```
while (fgets(flightInfo, sizeof flightInfo, fp)  > 0)
{

    clearTrailingCarraigeReturn(flightInfo);
    // display the line we got from the file
    printf("  >>> read record [%s]\n", flightInfo);
}
```

Reads the next line into flightInfo (which is an array of `char`), and when the next line comes along its re-read into the beginning of flightInfo all over again.  The very last line read will be stored in flightInfo.

You need to **store** the line as well, if you want to keep it around.  EG, you might do something like:

```
char multiple_flight_info[100][1024];
int i = 0;
while (fgets(multiple_flight_info[i], 1024, fp)  > 0)
{
    clearTrailingCarraigeReturn(flightInfo[i]);
    // display the line we got from the file
    printf("  >>> read record [%s]\n", flightInfo);
    i++;
    if (i > 100) { exit(1); } /* do better error exiting here */
}
```

Essentially this creates a double array.  The first index is the line number being read, and the second index is the character position in the line read.

There is a lot more that needs to be done to be "safe" and not reading partial lines because one is too long, etc.  But this may get you started.

Comment: `while (fgets(multiple_flight_info[i], 1024, fp) > 0)` should be `while (fgets(multiple_flight_info[i], 1024, fp) != NULL)`